# Errata for Jeff Miller's "Earliest ..."

Tags: discussion

The [websites](http://jeff560.tripod.com/) of Jeff Miller are a very valuable resource which get cited often here on hsm. Unfortunately, in a few occasion the information there has turned out to be incomplete or mistaken, so the idea of starting a list of errata on hsm was voiced some time ago in a comment by Francois Ziegler.

I find that a good idea in principle, but I see that the website is still actively being mantained (for example [this](http://jeff560.tripod.com/g.html) page was revised in May 2018) so if we start a list on hsm and the website adopts the changes, our list would also need to be updated regularly.

I would prefer if there was a way to submit errata directly to the maintainer of the website. Unfortunately I cannot find any contact information on the website.

> Is there a way to contact the author of Jeff Miller's "Earliest"? If so, are errata welcome?

In case no one has an answer to that question, what do people think of starting a wiki question on hsm with errata?

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry, I haven’t noticed this until now!) An address is found at [symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html). Many years ago, I sent a few things and they turned up after vetting by the writer of the relevant entry. My impression is that proactive maintenance dwindled with the closure of [Historia-Matematica](http://mathforum.org/kb/forum.jspa?forumID=149), where many entries were originally discussed. Absent such an open forum, doing it by email seems just too tedious.

Now hsm and mathoverflow are two such fora, with built-in vetting and much better ability to write mathematics, link evidence, etc.; but the *many* errata we keep finding (still [last week](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/why-statistical-moments-are-called-moments#comment13835_7582)) are scattered and apparently not easy enough to harvest. So I am all for devoting a question to this, and happy to contribute pointers to errata I come across again. Then, up to them or anyone to use it or not.

Suggestions:

- Make it community wiki.
- Emphasize it’s meant constructively and not to shame or replace *Earliest Uses*.
- Request short answers, each linking *one* disputed entry and its correction debated *elsewhere*.
- An errata is an *earlier* use. No need to [claim](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/who-introduced-moments-of-a-random-variable-first#comment13099_7346) or [require](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/who-first-had-the-idea-to-study-surfaces-via-rings-of-functions-as-in-algebraic/6066#comment10399_6066) *earliest*.

Comment: Thanks, I think I’ll do that. Btw, It was really hard to find this meta.hsm site from the main hsm page. So I was not surprised for not getting any answers here.